# How to send a message from parent process to multiple fork children?

Tags: c, fork, mkfifo

I have a server that allows clients to connect and I am using `select()` to manage new connections or incoming messages from already connected clients. For every 2 clients connected I create a child using `fork()`, remembering their file descriptors.

---

I want the child processes to wait for parent to send information along with the file descriptor of the socket associated with the client that sent that information. All the children read this and only the child associated with that client performs a certain task with that information while the rest of them go back to waiting to read a new message from parent (the other child does this as well after finishing that task).

---

My idea would be to write the message in a fifo file, copied on newlines by `nr_of_children` times (otherwise only one child could read as the information is consumed) and to have the child processes read from it, using a lock on the fifo so only one process reads a line at a time.

---

Is there a better way to do this, and if not, is my idea going to do the job?
Thank you.

Comment: You question is a bit hard to read because it is a single big block of text. You might want to break it up into a number of paragraphs/sections, maybe adding titles along the way to make it clear what you already have and what exactly you need help with.

Comment: If your server parent process knows which child is the only child that actually needs to process an action, it probably makes more sense to create a pipe for each child before forking, rather than a single "named" fifo pipe on the filesystem.

Comment: @aschepler Your idea might actually do it, I will make a vector of structs that contain the pipe file descriptors and the 2 file descriptors for the sockets of the associated clients.  This way I will send only to the desired child while the rest wait for information to be written to their pipe. Thank you